# How to get __dirname of a file before webpack bundling

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I'm making and app that deals with serialization and dynamic imports: I serialize objects of some class with something like this

```
fs.write('savename.json', JSON.stringify(someObject.getSerializable()), () => console.log('done'))
```

this way though I don't get to save the constructor name or any info about the prototype or stuff, so I save the constructor name in a property `type` like this:

```
export default class SomeObjectClass {

  // [...]

  getSerializable(): string {
    return {
      type: this.constructor.name,
      ...this
    }
  }
}
```

but in this way I don't save its full path, so when I try to dynamically import it with

```
const plainObject = fs.readFileSync('savename.json').toString();
const ctor = await import(plainObject.type);
const object = new ctor.default(); // this fails
```

it just fails, because the module was in a nested folder somewhere in my project.
I tried to concatenate `__dirname` like this

```
export default class SomeObjectClass {

  // [...]

  getSerializable(): string {
    return {
      type: path.join(__dirname, this.constructor.name),
      ...this
    }
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work because after bundling `__dirname` returns the path relative to the distribution folder that has different structure than my source folder.

So. How do I get the file path before webpack processing at runtime?
Alternative solutions to the problem are obviously welcome.

Cheers

Comment: if it is possible, try to save your dynamically imported files into a folder, let say `modules` and provide relative path from your `SomeObjectClass` file to `modules`, and then import with the relative path to `modules`. something like `const ctor = await import('../modules'+plainObject.type);`

Comment: Yes, having a fixed folder works, unfortunately though I need to support arbitrary folder structures. I can limit my modules, say, to folder 'src', but I need to be able to nest folders inside it.